# Two instances of AngularJS directive, changes to 2nd affects 1st instance.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a directive that in the link function will change the image thumbnail based on when the  has a change made to it. I have 2 instances of this directive on the same page. One belonging to each controller, the main controller and the edit controller. When I try to change the image belonging to the directive instance in the edit state (child of main), the change is made to the 1st instance of the directive in the main state and not the 2nd. Any help would be appreciated.

```
(function() {
'use strict';
/* @ngInject */

angular.module('MerchantPortalApp.directives.imageUpload', [])
    .directive('imageUpload', imageUpload);

function imageUpload($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            file: '=',
            img: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'global/directives/imageUpload/imageUpload.html',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

            var errorMsg = $(el.find('#error'));
            var fileInput = $(el.find('#fileInput'));
            var imageDisplayArea = $(el.find('#logoThumb')[0]);

            // Watch for user change on file input
            fileInput.change(function(e) {
                // Grab file from files array
                var file = fileInput.prop('files')[0];

                // REGEX to make sure file type is image
                var imageType = /image.*/;

                if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
                    // Create formData object and append the file object to it
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
                    scope.file = formData;

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    // Remove any previous images from div
                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                        imageDisplayArea.prop('src', reader.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                   errorMsg.show();
                }
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}
})();
```

Comment: Your `file` and `img` do not look to be shared between your directives, as they are part of the isolate scope for each. You should share this data between directives with a service.

Comment: They are not supposed to be share between instances of the directive. I have an add view (tied to the main state), and an edit state. Theoretically, a user could navigate to the edit view and while in edit of that reward program also open up the add view. So if they try to edit the image of the existing reward program, it instead updates the image in the add view. But I want them to be independent.

Answer (score 0):

`el.find('#error')` is  clear indication that you are repeating ID's in page....but ID's must be unique by definition.

Change all of the repeated ID's to class and switch the jQuery selectors accordingly:

```
el.find('.error')
```

Also, if your controllers are sharing a data service that is bound to the `scope.file` in directive make sure the 2 controllers aren't referencing the same service object

Comment: If I change to $(el,find('.fileInput')) and $(el.find('.logoThumb')), won't that target both instances of them? How do I get it to target just the first instance of that element in the template for that instance of the directive?

Comment: Show the basic html structure in question. Hopefully these directives aren't nested inside each other are they?